# конкатенация файлов с помощью gulp (sourcemap)

Tags: gulp

допустим я хочу собрать несколько файлов, в моем случае все файлы находятся в одной директории (jquery), но в проекте файлы по некоторым причинам будут браться из разных директорий

первый вариант сборки:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('myTask', function () {
    gulp.src([
        './jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js',
        './jquery/jquery.cookie.js',
        './jquery/toastr.min.js'
    ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat({ path: 'bundle-jquery.js' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и если посмотреть на скрин, то можно увидеть, что все файлы валяются в корне. что является не правильным.
п.с.: здесь я не дописываю к файлу хеш, т.к. изначально работает не верно

второй вариант сборки у меня выглядет так:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concatSource = require('gulp-concat-sourcemap');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');

gulp.task('myTask', function () {
    gulp.src([
        './jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js',
        './jquery/jquery.cookie.js',
        './jquery/toastr.min.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concatSource('bundle-jquery.js', { sourcesContent: true }))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
        .pipe(rev.manifest('bundle-jquery.json'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./manifests'));
});
```

здесь идет сборка через другой плагин и этот же плагин занимается мэппингом, вроде все хорошо. но как только я хочу переименовать файл (добавить хэш), то в соурсмепе осталось старое имя файла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. мне надо вручную поправить имя файла и все начинает работать верно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можете помочь с данной проблемой?